# Reloading docset without restarting Xcode

Tags: xcode, documentation, appledoc, docset

I am using appledoc for generating docsets. Everything is good, except everytime I rebuild it(with using my plist and run shell script) I must restart xcode to see changes.

Is there a way for force xcode to reload docset ?

Answer (score 1):

Not really what you're after and a shameless pitch of one of my apps, but you might want to use [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash) for documentation browsing/searching, where you won't have that problem :)