# Xcode 4.4: Reloading docset Without Restarting Windows

Tags: xcode4.4

It seems the script presented at [Reloading docset without restarting Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432780/reloading-docset-without-restarting-xcode/11540598#11540598) no longer works with the latest release 4.4.1 of Xcode.

```
tell application "Xcode"
    load documentation set with path
        "~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/myDocSet.docset"
end tell
```

Quitting and then relaunching Xcode are required.

Any idea on how to update the script to avoid quitting and relaunching?

Answer (score 2):

With Xcode version 4.5.1 (4G1004), the reload is done automatically.

So, no script needed :)

Here is what I use to generate the documentation, maybe it can help you:

```
appledoc --project-name "MyProjectName" --project-company "Awesome Company" --no-repeat-first-par --output docset_folder --ignore .m .
```

Comment: Yeah works without reloading Xcode, I only used the basic switches and the new DocSet is seen after opening the Organizer window: ./appledoc --project-name testdocs --project-company "My Company" --company-id com.mycompany --output ~/Desktop ~/Desktop/appledoc-master

Comment: It does reload the documentation page, but the navigation tree, help index and quick help is not updated.